# Why does click Event in Fragment takes back to the last activity without any such instruction given in the setOnClickListener in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

This question is an extension to previous question over here. [First Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61549346/getarguements-in-fragment-not-reading-the-strings-sent-from-activity/61549458#61549458)

So the logged in user and chatbuddy names are not returning null any more and data is being inserted in firebase as well. However the setOnClickListener action takes back to previous UsersList.java activity even though no such Intent given in sendImgView.setOnClickListener() function.

UserList.java relevant code takes to ChatActivity as you can see and also i finish() it on click-

```
usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub




           Intent goChatActivity = new Intent(UserList.this, ChatActivity.class);


            String currentUser = "Abdul";
            String chatBuddy = "Razzak";

            goChatActivity.putExtra("currentUser", currentUser);
            goChatActivity.putExtra("chatBuddy", chatBuddy);
            startActivity(goChatActivity);
            finish(); **//finishing UsersList here**

        }
    });
```

And in the SendMsgFragment.java after inserting data in firebase I do getActivity().finish(); but sendImgView.setOnClickListener action taking back to UsersList.java from where I came to SendMsgFragment using Intent. How do I prevent that from happening -

SendMsgFragment.java relevant code is -

```
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.send_msg_fragment, container, false);
        sendImgView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
   sendImgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    currentUser = getArguments().getString("currentUser");
                    chatBuddy = getArguments().getString("chatBuddy");
                }catch (Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                Chat chat = new Chat(chatEditText.getText().toString(), cal.getTime().toString());
                databaseReference.child(currentUser+"/"+currentUser+"_"+chatBuddy).push().setValue(chat);
                chatEditText.setText("");
                getActivity().finish(); //finishing ChatActivity where I load this fragment
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: first `finish` will destroy the current activity and  second one will destroy the host activity of that fragment, and why would you finish this activity from launching from launching another from this one, don't do that

Comment: even after removing both the finish() in fragment and activity still sendImgView.setOnClickListener() takes me back to UsersList.java.

Comment: who is the host of sendmsgfragment?

Comment: the host of the said fragment is ChatActivity.java

Comment: so chatactivity will be destroyed from the clicklistener, and the activity behind it is the activity which is showing up

Comment: what do i do to keep ChatActivity alive after click..as i want to show chat conversation..in the same activity after every message sent

Comment: in the click listener replace the current fragment with the chat conversation fragment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212970/discussion-between-sakib-shaikh-and-abhinav-chauhan).